# Gradle error arise when run the flutter app in android emulator

Tags: flutter, android-studio, gradle, android-emulator

**Showing error like below when i tried to run flutter app on android emulator**

Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone x86 in debug mode...
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timeout of 120000 reached waiting for exclusive access to file: C:\Users\gobi.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-7.6.3-all\aocdy2d2z8kodnny3rsumj8i8\gradle-7.6.3-all.zip
at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:61)
at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:128)
at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
[!] Gradle threw an error while downloading artifacts from the network.
Retrying Gradle Build: #1, wait time: 100ms

i tried to run gradle command in command prompt to check the version of the gradle but it shows the gradle was not recognised.